# Star is coming in left side but i did not put code for that what is that mean in react

Tags: reactjs, layout

I am doing a project all thigs are going good . but a annoying star is coming on all pages . I am not understanding why it is coming   .
[image]

Comment: check your upside components like layout you are gonna find the code for it if you are using vscode copy the star and search all of your code using ctrl+shif+F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Run the application in chrome.
2.Inspect the element.
3.By inspecting you will get to know that why its coming.
4.Make some changes.